# Java. Нужна помощь в создании итератора простых чисел

Tags: java, итераторы

Я сделал итератор простых чисел и вроде в нем все работает. Но мое задание буквально звучало так: "**Сделать итератор возвращающий простые числа.**"

А у меня получился итератор в котором есть метод определяющий является ли это число простым. И сколько я не ломаю голову как сделать так чтобы пользовательский класс мог использовать только методы `next()` и `hasNext()` не как не получается. У меня возвращаются все а потом я проверяю простое или нет.

Помогите пожалуйста сделать из моего кода так чтобы именно **возвращались** только простые.

```
public class PrimeIterator implements Iterator {
    private final int[] values;
    private int index = 0;

    public PrimeIterator(final int[] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return index < values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        return values[index++];
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int number) {
        if (number <= 0 || number == 1)
            return false;

        if (number == 2)
            return true;

        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrimeIterator pi = new PrimeIterator(
                new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ,12, 13});

        while (pi.hasNext()) {
            int number = (int) pi.next();
            if (pi.isPrime(number))
                System.out.println(number);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Итератор связан с множеством каких-либо объектов, например, с некоторой коллекцией, поэтому постановка задачи -- `Сделать итератор возвращающий простые числа.` звучит весьма странно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `hasNext` - это `return true`, т. к. последовательность бесконечна.
2. В приватное поле загоняешь последнее возвращённое число.
3. `next` в цикле находит следующее за сохранённым простое, обновляет сохранённое и возвращает его.

Вроде все.

Если нужно добавить верхнее ограничение, то можно:

1. Сохранённое число не превосходит лимит.
2. Сохраняешь следующее простое число (ну или лимитом + 1,если он достигнут).
3. В переменную сохраняешь текущее сохранённое, а сохранённое апдейтишь следующим. Возвращаешь то, которое в переменной.

Если надо фильтровать числа из имеющегося массива.

1. Сравниваешь сохранённый индекс с длиной массива.
2. Вместо числа хранишь индекс в массиве.
3. Как в прошлом, но используешь цикл по массиву.

Теперь точно всё :)